# Automating entire map production in ArcMap using ArcPy/ArcObjects?

Tags: arcpy, arcobjects

I am trying to gather some information on how to create maps based on an existing base map I have. The basemap has all the data loaded. So the user will enter data into a form and the  would do a save as, query data in the map, create the map and export to PDF.

I know python is for automation of workflows, but what I need is a way to have my users enter information into a form and have the map created automatically based on a save as of an existing map, some inputs, queries and data in my basemap. I see lots of examples for automating workflows, but I am looking to deploy a solution that non-GIS users could create maps quickly based on some information in arcmap.

Would I do this with ArcObjects or can it in fact be done with Python? Has anyone tried automating the entire map process?

I just need to know which method I would use to create this project? And if I can complete with Python and/or ArcObjects?

Comment: I would expect that your requirements can be met using ArcPy but as it stands your question seems too broad for our focussed Q&A format. I recommend starting to write some code snippets to do each step of your map automation and if you get stuck then research/ask here about each separately.

Comment: I am not looking for exactly how to do this, obviously it would be intensive. I am just wondering which method I could use to do this (Python/ArcObjects) and any info (links) that could help me during this gathering stage. I would be hiring developers for this project, I am just trying to obtain info as of now on the structure of this project.

Comment: Hey Myque - [arcpy.mapping](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000032000000) offers a great deal of control over the map automation functions it exposes. However, I'd say the central factor preventing a pure Python/ArcPy route is the fact that arcpy.mapping generally cannot _create_ map documents and associated map elements, it can only _manipulate existing elements_. So, the requirement to _create_ a map document and call outs etc. cannot be met with just ArcPy, see [This Example](https://darrenwiens.wordpress.com/2014/09/01/using-arcobjects-in-python/)

Comment: It will also depend on what application your users will be working with. Will they be using ArcMap? Or will they be entering information into a web form or some other custom application?

Comment: I don't believe you can create callout boxes with arcpy, but you can set the labeling symbology up beforehand to look like callout boxes.

Comment: @ian without more detailed requirements it's not possible to be sure but some people use the term callout for inset maps with leader lines and these can be authored into a map for manipulation by ArcPy.

Comment: @PolyGeo interesting.. I've always known them as the labels like in this image: http://i.imgur.com/rbGGGiA.png

Comment: @Jim the asker says they have an existing base map (a pre-authored map document?) and so the process of "creating a map" may not need an MXD to be created by ArcPy - just modify the existing base map.

Comment: @Ian that's always my first thought too

Comment: Now that we have had this discussion in comments I think it should be possible for you to **edit** your question into a form more suited to focussed Q&A around a single requirement, and then to research/ask about any others of concern separately.

Comment: I edited my question, will this work better for trying to get some simple information based on my request?

Comment: What you are describing sounds like [On Demand PDF Maps](http://discoverspatial.com/courses/on-demand-pdf-maps) for which I have released an eLearning video course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking can be done using arcpy/python. Below is a script that I compiled to create an mxd and update map element with user inputs. Feel free to use the script, I never took it further than making an mxd.

The script relies on having an mxd already set up as a template. Additionally, in order for the script to work, you need to assign the map elements (text boxes, legends, North Arrows etc)a unique name. e.g. If you open the properties of a text box and click the Size and Position tab, there should be a field called Element Name. Enter the unique name of the element there. See image below.

[image]

In the code below, arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) to (4) are used to compile the file name for the mxd. The other arcpy.GetParameterAsText(*) are the users inputs to add to the map elements. The line "for txtElement in txtElements:" is where the code starts assigning the users inputs to the map elements. Hope this makes sense.

```
import arcpy, sys, traceback, datetime, os, shutil, getpass
from arcpy.mapping import *

groupDesigLetter = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
#    Designates map is generated by the certain team (e.g. G = Geospatial)

mapNumber = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
#    The next map in sequence.

workingOrSubmittal = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
#    If it is a working document or final document.

projectNumber = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
#    This is the project number.

versionNo = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
#    v1. One digit sub-version number. 0 or blank denotes a map that has been issued.
#    “1,2,3…” denotes internal, intermediate revisions of map before releasing the      map
#    to an external party.

mapDescription = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
#    Description of the map and contents should include page size, orientation, title etc

mapFormat = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
#    This is the size and orientation of the map.

mapTitle = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)
#    This is the tile of the map

mapSubTitle = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8)
#    This is the sub title of the map

figureNumber = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(9)
#    This is the figure number of the map.

mapProjection = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(10)

saveMXD = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(11)
#    This is the location where the new mxd is saved

newMXDFileName = "{}{}_{}_{}_v{}_{}_{}.mxd".format(groupDesigLetter, mapNumber, workingOrSubmittal, projectNumber, versionNo, mapDescription, mapFormat[:2])
#    New file name for the .mxd

newMXDFullPath = os.path.join(saveMXD, newMXDFileName)
#    Variable to store the full directory path to the new mxd.

mxdLocation = os.path.join("D:\Templates", mapFormat +".mxd")
#    Location of the mxd template

mxdAuthor = getpass.getuser()
#    Gets the current user name

mxdTitle = "{} - {}".format(mapTitle,mapSubTitle)
#    Compiles the mxd title

mxdCredits = "XXXXXXXXX {}".format(datetime.date.today().year)

try:

    arcpy.AddMessage("...Creating Copy of Template...")
    #    Prints message to screen.

    shutil.copy(mxdLocation, saveMXD)
    #    Copies template .mxd to the save location.

    arcpy.AddMessage("...Renaming Copied MXD...")
    #    Prints message to screen.

    rename = os.rename(os.path.join(saveMXD, mapFormat + ".mxd"), os.path.join(saveMXD, newMXDFileName))
    #    Renames the copies .mxd to the new file name

    mxd = MapDocument(newMXDFullPath)
    #    Variable to store the location to the working map document.

    mxd.author = mxdAuthor
    #    Assigns the current user as the author

    mxd.title = mxdTitle
    #    Assigns the attribute for the mxds title property

    mxd.description = mapDescription
    #    Assigns the attribute for the mxds description property

    mxd.relativePaths = True
    #    Sets the relative path to true.

    mxd.credits = mxdCredits

    dataFrame = ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]

    dataFrame.spatialReference = mapProjection

    txtElements = ListLayoutElements(mxd,'TEXT_ELEMENT')
    #    variable to store the list of text elements within the working map document.

    for txtElement in txtElements:
        #    Loop for the text elements within the working map document.

        if txtElement.name == 'Title_Block':
            #    if statement to select the title block map element

            txtElement.text = "{}\r\n {}".format(mapTitle.upper(), mapSubTitle)
            #    Populates the tilte block's text properties

        elif txtElement.name == 'Project_Number':
            #    If statement to select the project number map element.

            txtElement.text = projectNumber
            #    Populates the project number text properties.

        elif txtElement.name == 'Version_Number':
            #    If statement to select the version number map element.

            txtElement.text = "v{}".format(versionNo)
            #    Populates the version number text properties.

        elif txtElement.name == 'Figure_Number':
            #    If statement to select the figure number map element.

        txtElement.text = '<FNT name = "Arial Narrow" size = "12">Map</FNT>\r\n{}'.format(figureNumber)
        #     Populates the figure number text properties.

    elif txtElement.name == 'Projection':
        #    If statement to select the figure number map element.

        if mapProjection[8:25] == "XXXXXX":

            txtElement.text = 'XXXXXXX {}'.format(mapProjection[26:28])
            #     Populates the figure number text properties.

        elif mapProjection[8:20] == "XXXXXXX":

            txtElement.text = "XXXXXXX"

        else:

            txtElement.text = "Unknown"

    else:

        continue
        #    Continues with the loop

    arcpy.AddMessage(mapProjection)

    arcpy.AddMessage(mapProjection[8:20])

    arcpy.AddMessage("...Saving MXD...")
    #    Prints message to screen.

    mxd.save()
    #    Save the above changes to the new mxd

    arcpy.AddMessage("...Finished Creating Map...")
    #    Prints message to screen.


except:


    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n     " +        str(sys.exc_type) + ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"
    msgs = "ARCPY ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"

    arcpy.AddError(msgs)
    arcpy.AddError(pymsg)

    print msgs
    print pymsg

   arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages(1))
   print arcpy.GetMessages(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would offer a hybrid solution.. Write your python to be executed from the command line then create a form that collects the required information and executes the python.

The difficult part of the python is the lack of forms; ArcObjects could do this but the code would be easily ten times as long.. I would suggest it's easier to use a quick form for what it's good for and a python script for what that's good for.

I have used this method for C++ tools, I wrote the tools for console (command line) and newer users (younger users) are scared of command line so I put together a quick form in Visual Studio that compiles a batch file then executes it - saved a *lot* of time rewriting existing (working, debugged) tools in C# or MFC.

Distribute your tool with the python script then use the [tool location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application) to call the python file with arguments.